# How can i find the path of a google drive folder

Tags: google-drive-api

How can i find the path of this folder? It shows that I am the owner of this folder, but i can't find it anywhere. There are file inside that are using up space but i don't know how to navigate to this folder. Any ideas?

[image]

I tried to search for those file, but I always end up in this view of the folder where i cannot see its path.

Comment: Is this folder located on your own Drive or on a Shared Drive or shared with you by another user?

Answer (score -1):

to find path of any file or folder on your pc you can simply use command prompt.
go to your search bar and type cmd, go to command prompt and type

dir "*folder name*" /s

it will show you the directory of any file or folder you want to find on your system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).